# Если я перезагружу компьютер то придется заново собирать проект через cmake?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, cmake, llvm

Сейчас собираю LLVM на Windows через команду cmake --build .

Если я сейчас перезагружу компьютер, то смогу ли я продолжить сборку после этого или придется заново?

Если есть такой способ, то расскажите мне о нем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сон, гибернация, дождаться окончания сборки и выключить комп, положить записку чтоб не выключали комп. Если завершить в момент работы, то придется заново с небольшим исключением, то что было скомпилировано, не будет еще раз компилироваться.

Comment: Сон или гибернация лучше в этом случае? :)

Comment: Не попробуешь - не узнаешь.

Comment: @Editaw5, при гибернации программы не прерываются, хотя она и может на них повлиять. Теоретически должно получиться.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы на вопросы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, "при гибернации программы не прерываются", не прерываются или ты перепутал со сном?

Comment: @Editaw5, не прерываются. Оперативная память записывается на жёсткий диск, а при включении - обратно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм. Я поставил на гибернацию, после 4 часов включил, а там у меня всё собралось. Как так?

Comment: @Editaw5, не знаю. Либо оно собралось пока ты ставил на гибернацию или включал, либо оно всё-таки как-то реагирует на гибернацию и прерывает билд, правда тогда непонятно, почему успешно собралось, а не упало.